# π input inside siunitx commands

Tags: siunitx, unicode-math

What I’m trying to do is typeset μ₀ value (4π×10⁻⁷ SI) with siunitx using unicode input.

Without unicode it would look like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \SI{4 \pi e-7}{SI}
\end{document}
```

And that does work. Based on [Maths symbols and unicode-math input inside siunitx commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479968/56823) as well as siunitx documentation defining default value of `input-symbols` to `{\pi \dots}`, I’ve tried the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[input-symbols = {π}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    \SI{4πe-7}{SI}
\end{document}
```

But this results in: `! Package siunitx Error: Invalid token 'π' in numerical input.`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you put `\sisetup{input-symbols=π}` after `\begin{document}` you don't get the error (but the π isn't output...), strange.

Comment: Is this useful this link for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560571/%cf%80-input-inside-siunitx-commands/560593#560593

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz The π appears when a font containing Greek glyphs is used (e.g., Noto Serif). The default font, Latin Modern, has no Greek.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz @Cicada More precisely, it’s because by default the text font is used (through `mathrm`), and it needs to have a greek alphabet (with U+03C0 GREEK SMALL LETTER PI, π), which is rather found in math fonts. @ulrike-fisher told me to use `\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}` to work around this issue.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Thanks, but… it does not work enclosed within `\AtBeginDocument{}`… It really has to be at the beginning of the document then, and that’s definitively not practical when my headers are supposed to be shared amongst hundreds of documents. Any idea why so? Would that be a bug?

Comment: @Archange Works for me, but only after setting up some Math font with `\setmathfont`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue why you can't put `\sisetup` in `\AtBeginDocument` in your preamble is, that the wrong catcode is used. In LuaTeX `π` is of category 11 in the preamble, but with `unicode-math` it'll be of category 12 in the document. So you have to change the catcode before you use `\AtBeginDocument` (with `mathrm=sym` thanks to Ulrike):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\begingroup
\catcode`\π=12
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{input-symbols=π}}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
    \SI{4πe-7}{SI}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, so they were 3 issues in one. But it’s finally nailed down. :)